# java redirect 301 but browser not open correctly new url

Tags: java, tomcat, redirect, servlets

I moved all data in old domain to new one. Many links is indexed by google and its important for us So I want to redirect 301 all link like below:

> my_domain.ir/Server?do=content&id=24

to

> my_domain.com/Server?do=content&id=24

The code below is Server.java that is a servlet

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {        
    System.out.println("_______________________________________________");

    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString() +"?"+ request.getQueryString();
    System.out.println(url);// http://my_domain.ir/Server?do=content&id=24
    url = url.replace(".ir", ".com");
    url = url.replace("localhost:9090", "mydomain.com");//to test from localhost
    System.out.println(url);//http://my_domain.com/Server?do=content&id=24
    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_MOVED_PERMANENTLY);
    response.setHeader("Location", url);
    response.setHeader( "Connection", "close" );
    System.out.println("_______________________________________________");
}
```

after calling I can see http://my_domain.ir i can see 301 redirect code But in address bar is "http://my_domain.com/Server" and browser dos not open any page.

I try redirect all to http://my_domain.com/index_test.html but the result is same.

Its vary important for us to save my domain position in google, Is this problem harmful?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to do with a rewrite rule in your HTTP server?

Comment: Unfortunately I can not access tomcat config in this server. But may be Server admin make some change but it is not so reliably.

Comment: Maybe your browser is set up to not follow 301 responses.

Comment: I test it other browser and other system,

Answer (score 0):

Just looked it up, because I remembered this (from like 10 years ago), but you can do a redirect much easier:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {        
    System.out.println("_______________________________________________");

    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString() +"?"+ request.getQueryString();
    System.out.println(url);// http://my_domain.ir/Server?do=content&id=24
    url = url.replace(".ir", ".com");
    url = url.replace("localhost:9090", "mydomain.com");//to test from localhost
    System.out.println(url);//http://my_domain.com/Server?do=content&id=24
    response.sendRedirect(url);
    System.out.println("_______________________________________________");
}
```

Disclaimer: I haven't checked whether your URL rewriting is actually correct.